# How to extract nested map properties into root class?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I have two simple entities:

```kotlin
class EntityA @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING) constructor(
   
    val entityB: EntityB
) : DomainEvent {
 //How to include propertyTwo and propertyThree here?
}
```

```kotlin
class EntityB @JsonCreator constructor (
    @JsonProperty("propertyTwo")
    val propertyTwo:String,

    @JsonProperty("propertyThree")
    val propertyThree:String ;
) {

   

}
```

With this mapping I need this result JSON serialization and deserialization:

```json
{
    "propertyOne": "",
    "propertyTwo": "",
    "propertyThree": "",
}
```

Is there any way to mapping this scenario with Jackson annotations in EntityB class or entityB property? If not, how do I create a custom deserializer to help me with this issue?

***Unfortunately its not possible today, use data class with this approach. So was needed comment "propertyOne".***

### The final solution I used:

```
class EntityA @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING) constructor(
    //@JsonProperty("propertyOne")
    //val propertyOne:String,
    
    @field:JsonUnwrapped val entityB: EntityB
) : DomainEvent {
 //How to include propertyTwo and propertyThree here?
}
```

But apparently there is a error with data class and @JsonUnwrapper :

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/56

Comment: You'll need your own deserializer. Lots of examples on the web. Here's a good place to start.

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: You are right. Create the deserializer its the only way, because I have two properties.